# Erro na inserção de dados no mysql e php

Tags: php, html, mysql, funções, query

sou meio iniciante mexendo com php e gostaria de alguma ajuda pra entender o pq ta acontecendo isso

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, quando eu executo a a seguinte function do php, ele nao me retorna nada no fetch como eu pedi e nao consigo fazer a comparação corretamente no if

Gostaria de encontrar alguma solução pra fazer a consulta, retornar o numero de linhas que existem na consulta e fazer com que eu consiga comparar pra saber se o usuario existe ou nao pra poder cadastrar ele no banco de dados, Segue o codigo da function

```
 function cadastrar($nome, $email, $senha, $empresa, $nmPage, $user){
     $stm="CALL insec(:user, :snha, :emal, :emp, :nmPega, :nme)";
     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=loginads', 'root', '');

     $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loginuser where usuario = :user  or  email = :email");
     $sql -> bindValue(":email", $email);
     $sql -> bindValue(":user", $user);
     $sql -> execute();

    if (!$sql -> fetch() > 0) {
        echo"Login e senha ja existem";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //cadastrar
        $sql = $pdo -> prepare ($stm);
        $sql -> bindValue(":usr", $user);
        $sql -> bindValue(":snha", $senha);
        $sql -> bindValue(":emal", $email);         
        $sql -> bindValue(":emp", $empresa);
        $sql -> bindValue(":nmPega", $nmPage);
        $sql -> bindValue(":nme", $nome);
        $sql -> execute();
        return true;
    }

}
```

esse aqui é o código da conexão com o banco:

```
 function conectar(){
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=loginads', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return array('conexao' =>$pdo ,"mensagem" => "Sucesso" );
     
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return array("conexao" => null, "mensagem" =>'ERROR: <br> ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

e esse é o codigo que está executando a function :

```
require_once 'ProcessaDadosLogin.php';

$u = new Processa();

if(isset($_POST['nome']))
{
    $Nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $Senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $Empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $NmPage = $_POST['nmPage'];
    $Usuario = $_POST['user'];

    if (!empty($Nome) && !empty($Senha) && !empty($Empresa) && !empty($Email) && !empty($NmPage) && !empty($Usuario)) { 
        $u -> conectar();
        if (empty($msgError)) {
            if ($u -> cadastrar($Nome, $Email, $Senha, $Empresa, $NmPage, $Usuario)) {
                echo "cadComsucesso";
                header('Location: contatoht.php');
                                
            }
            else{
                echo "Login e senha ja existem";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "erro de conexão" .$u -> $msgError;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "preencha tudo, não deixe campos vazios";
    }
}
else{
        echo "preencha o campo nome";
}
```

nesse cado do codigo tentei usar algumas coisas mas nao to conseguindo identificar aonde ta o erro pfv preciso de ajuda, eles estavam funcionando antes porem não estava fazendo nenhum tipo de comparação apartir banco de dados estou utilizando o xammp, agora nao cadastra nem mesmo mostra alguma mensagem de erro

Comment: Tentou tirar os espaços entre esse simbolo ` -> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Me parece que você não está atribuindo o retorno do **fetch** para ninguém.
Nas linhas:

```
if (!$sql -> fetch() > 0) {
    echo"Login e senha ja existem";
    return false;
}
```

Faça o seguinte:

```
$linhas = $sql->fetchAll();
if(count($linhas)){ 
    echo "Login e senha já existem";
    return false;
}
```